# How to tell a participle from an adjective?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, participle

What's the right way to tell a present passive participle from an adjective? I guess if the agent is mentioned (like in "Изменяемый **мною** проект"), then it's for sure a participle. But what about such cases, in which the agent is not mentioned? Like the ones below:

> СМИ уже больше не обращают никакого внимания на постоянно
>   **изменяемые** проекты городского правительства.
>
> Всё это **изменяемые** величины, а не константы.
>
> В отличие от "пианино" и "пальто" такие слова как "машина", "ковёр" и
>   "контракт" - всё это **изменяемые** по падежам слова.

Comment: Maybe, the participles mean "the ones which _are being changed_" (your example #1), and the adjectives mean "the ones that _can be changed_" (your examples #2 and #3)?

Comment: @YellowSky - I think you've nailed it! Please, re-write your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the participles mean "the ones which *are being changed*" (your example #1), and the adjectives mean "the ones that *can be changed*" (your examples #2 and #3).
Anyhow, it is very difficult even for the native speakers of Russian to distinguish between the participles and the adjectives.

Comment: What about _любимый_?

Comment: @jwalker - And what about _любимый_? According to its meaning in a particular sentence, it can be either a participle or an adjective.

Comment: But as an adjective it doesn't mean _the one that can be loved_. I agree the "can" meaning is often valid, but it doesn't seem to be definitive.

Comment: @jwalker - Ah, I see your point. My answer refers only to the 3 examples of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

A participle is a form of a verb that describes change over time.  An adjective describes a more permanent attribute.

What makes example #1 ***постоянно изменяемые*** different from the other two is that it describes a ***change over time***.